# Scanning and Authentication of NFC Tag using CoreNFC in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, ndef, core-nfc

Hello All I am trying to scan and Authenticate the password protected tag using Ntag213 using CoreNFC library in IOS Swift.I used the sample code provided in the apple site.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

since the Tag is compatible with the Mifare commands I am using the Mifare command to authenticate. I have provided the values of PWD and PACK. still its not able to scan and read the Tag. I have modified the MessagesTableViewController file of that as below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

/// - Tag: MessagesTableViewController
class MessagesTableViewController: UITableViewController, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    let reuseIdentifier = "reuseIdentifier"
    var detectedMessages = [NFCNDEFMessage]()
    var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    /// - Tag: beginScanning
    @IBAction func beginScanning(_ sender: Any) {
        guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Scanning Not Supported",
                message: "This device doesn't support tag scanning.",
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
        session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
        session?.begin()
    }
    
    // MARK: - NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate
    
    /// - Tag: processingTagData
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Process detected NFCNDEFMessage objects.
            self.detectedMessages.append(contentsOf: messages)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func addMessage(fromUserActivity ndefMessage: NFCNDEFMessage) {
        // Add the message to the list of detected messages
        detectedMessages.append(ndefMessage)
        
        // Reload the table view
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
        guard let tag = tags.first else {
            return
        }

        session.connect(to: tag) { error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle connection error
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                session.invalidate()
                return
            }

            if let miFareTag = tag as? NFCMiFareTag {
                
                let uid = miFareTag.identifier

                    // Print the tag's UID
                    print("Tag UID: \(uid)")
                // Get the password and PACK values from base64
                let pwdBytes = Data(base64Encoded: "xyzzzz")!
                let packBytes = Data(base64Encoded: "ABC")!

                // Authenticate the tag
                let authenticationCommand = Data([0x1B] + pwdBytes.map { $0 as UInt8 })


                miFareTag.sendMiFareCommand(commandPacket: authenticationCommand) { response, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Authentication failed
                        print("The tag is not authenticated")
                        session.invalidate()
                        return
                    }

                    // Authentication succeeded
                    // Continue with further operations
                    if response == packBytes {
                        print("The tag is authenticated")
                    } else {
                        print("The tag is not authenticated")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Handle unsupported tag type
                session.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        // Check the invalidation reason from the returned error.
        if let readerError = error as? NFCReaderError {
            // Show an alert when the invalidation reason is not because of a
            // successful read during a single-tag read session, or because the
            // user canceled a multiple-tag read session from the UI or
            // programmatically using the invalidate method call.
            if (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorFirstNDEFTagRead)
                && (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorUserCanceled) {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(
                    title: "Session Invalidated",
                    message: error.localizedDescription,
                    preferredStyle: .alert
                )
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                }}}}}
```

I tried the code provided as above as per the code it should scan and authenticated the Tag but its not doing it and I am not getting any errors.